# Access API endpoints EC2 + Node + ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, api, express, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance running Bitnami MEAN STACK. What I want to do is to set mongo and Node so as to call to the endpoints of my API. I wrote my `app.js` file, where I have implemented an API that connects to mongo.

- My doubt now is: how to connect to mongo? should I leave the mongo host with localhost as I am running it inside the EC2 instance? `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb');`
- Which is the URL to access my endpoints? In my EC2 instance I have run `node app.js` so now its running... Which is the URL where I can go in any browser and and do like `.../api/users'?

**api.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                    
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    
var methodOverride = require('method-override'); 
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt'),
    SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));            
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); 
app.use(methodOverride());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb'); 

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.redirect('/index.html');
});

app.all("/api/*", function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST");
  return next();
});

app.all("/api/*", function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.method.toLowerCase() !== "options") {
    return next();
  }
  return res.send(204);
});

// define model =================
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

// api ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// get all todos

/* USERS API */
app.get('/api/users', function(req, res) {

    // use mongoose to get all todos in the database
    User.find(function(err, users) {

        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
        if (err)
            res.send(err)

        res.json(users); // return all todos in JSON format
    });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to connect to mongo? should I leave the mongo host with localhost
>   as I am running it inside the EC2 instance?
>   mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb');

Yes, localhost if it is on the same server.

> Which is the URL to access my endpoints? In my EC2 instance I have run
>   node app.js so now its running... Which is the URL where I can go in
>   any browser and and do like `.../api/users'?

Go into the EC2 console and lookup the public IP address of your instance. Your URL will be something like `http://PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS/api/users`. You will have to open up the port in the security group, and possibly the firewall (iptables) on the EC2 server.

Comment: @Rüménok I don't understand what you are saying. I don't see how this comment is related to your question or my answer.